# Retrieve data from MongoDB using Mongolite nested query

Tags: mongodb, rscript

I am using mongolite package to retrieve data from MongoDB using R script. I need one framework data to be input to other. As below

### connecting mongodb

library(mongolite)

mongoSample<-mongolite::mongo(collection = "Sample1", db = "Test", url = 
                          "mongodb://User:123@Wyyuyu:13333/ty2_U",verbose = TRUE)

mongoSample2<-mongolite::mongo(collection = "Sample2", db = "Test", url = 
                          "mongodb://User:123@Wyyuyu:13333/ty2_U",verbose = TRUE)

### getting specific data from collection below query is working fine.

D$find(query = '{"_id":  "xyz"}', fields = "{\"_id\":1, \"description\":1,\"name\":1}", sort = "{}", skip = 0, limit = 0, handler = NULL, pagesize = 1000)

### But I want to filter passing values from another framework.

**As in SQL

SELECT * FROM Sample1 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Sample2)

Any help on this will be much appreciated.